# What is the use of of_device_id and i2c_device_id?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, i2c, device-tree

I was understanding an I2C driver for adxl34x sensor.
If I only keep of_device_id, my probe does not gets called, but if I include i2c_device_id probe gets called.
I checked for some explanation but I get to know that i2c_device_id is used for legacy purpose or board file matching. 
Here I am using device tree.
How is it possible that i2c_device_id is making the device recognised?
Is there a dependency in I2C drivers to use both i2c_Device_id and of_device_id??
here is my understanding on this top
 id_table is used for legacy i2c devices. See in this code

```
static const struct i2c_device_id *i2c_match_id(const struct i2c_device_id *id,
                        const struct i2c_client *client)
{
    while (id->name[0]) {
        if (strcmp(client->name, id->name) == 0)
            return id;
        id++;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

There is no device id table reference, while of_device_id

```
/**
 * of_match_device - Tell if a struct device matches an of_device_id list
 * @ids: array of of device match structures to search in
 * @dev: the of device structure to match against
 *
 * Used by a driver to check whether an platform_device present in the
 * system is in its list of supported devices.
 */
const struct of_device_id *of_match_device(const struct of_device_id *matches,
                       const struct device *dev)
{
    if ((!matches) || (!dev->of_node))
        return NULL;
    return of_match_node(matches, dev->of_node);
}
```

Uses dev->of_node

So its safe to say both mechanism are isolated and does not depend on each other.
Then why my driver is not getting probed by only using this,

```
/*
 static const struct i2c_device_id adxl34x_id[] = {
    { "adxl345", 0 },
    { }
};

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(i2c, adxl34x_id);
*/

#ifdef CONFIG_OF
static const struct of_device_id adxl34x_of_id[] = {
    /*
     * The ADXL346 is backward-compatible with the ADXL345. Differences are
     * handled by runtime detection of the device model, there's thus no
     * need for listing the "adi,adxl346" compatible value explicitly.
     */
    { .compatible = "adi,adxl345", },
    /*
     * Deprecated, DT nodes should use one or more of the device-specific
     * compatible values "adi,adxl345" and "adi,adxl346".
     */
    { .compatible = "adi,adxl34x", },
    { }
};

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, adxl34x_of_id);
#endif

static struct i2c_driver adxl34x_driver = {
    .driver = {
        .name = "adxl34x",
        //.pm = &adxl34x_i2c_pm,
        .of_match_table = of_match_ptr(adxl34x_of_id),
    },
    .probe    = adxl34x_i2c_probe,
    .remove   = adxl34x_i2c_remove,
    //.id_table = adxl34x_id, /*commented i2c_device_id*/
};
```

Here are some links that I have gone through in order to get some understanding

https://patches.linaro.org/patch/16873/

https://lists.ozlabs.org/pipermail/linuxppc-dev/2015-July/131965.html

https://i2c.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/OF_Modalias

I understood that first of_* style match will happen, then i2c_device_id type match.

In my case, then how of_* is not able to bind then?

Why i2c_device_table is needed if its legacy thing?

Comment: This question lacks more details. In particular, excerpts from device tree, `static struct platform_driver`, and perhaps other relevant info.

Comment: Added details., check once. I have commented i2c_device_id part from my driver.

Comment: Why downvote without giving explanation?

Comment: I haven't downvoted you. This happens here from time to time if people thinks the question is poorly written. Looks good to me though.

Comment: Ok. I'll wait for an answer.

Comment: It gets probed I'm pretty sure (check with `initcall_debug` added to the kernel command line). What you missed is the switch to `->probe_new()` callback. See this commit https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/wsa/linux.git/commit/?id=b8a1a4cd5a98a2adf8dfd6902cd98e57d910ee12

Comment: And this commit https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/sameo/nfc-next.git/commit/?id=8597c0920d6f4af66d2100b93599b0c0850dffdd  as an example what you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. It is true that you need to pass id_table along with the driver structure for I2C if you are using probe callback.

This is because the earlier I2C driver framework used older style of probe function signature that required i2c_device_id to be passed as the second parameter. However, this has now been replaced with i2c_probe_new callback whose function signature shows that it no more needs i2c_device_id parameter anymore.

Here is a link to this code change for reference:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.9/source/include/linux/i2c.h#L281